# joomla website uses too much CPU rsources

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a simple joomla 2.5 website with a rocketTheme template "Fracture". Recently they took down my website due to, too much CPU usage. I have tried to disable all the plug-in and the modules one by one and a check the CPU usage, no luck. Anyone has any idea what might have gone wrong in the website?

Comment: How are you expecting we might answer this? We don't know what your host saw, what plugins you're using, what custom code is involved, etc. The answer might just be to get a better host.

Comment: Joomla doesn't use your CPU its' PHP your HTTP server and database which executes queries and does all processing. Thats where you should be looking for the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem there were couple of IP addresses spamming the website (142,000 request per day). blocked those IPs and the problem solved.

IP addresses: 
69.197.155.235
192.151.147.58
37.59.29.107
188.143.235.9
and couple more ip addresses. I blocked those addresses and all the other IPs out of US.

Here is a website you can pick the country you want to block/allow and it gives you all the IPs:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block.php#blocklist

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have been infected with malware. I use many RocketTheme templates, and the only time I've had CPU usage issues is when a crappy webhost (rhymes with noonerpages) lets malware from other sites on their shared servers infect mine.

Here's a tool that can help verify if you've been hacked: http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

Cleaning up can be a hassle. Start by looking at the modified dates on your index.php files and seeing if any have been tampered with. Look for base64 stuff that shouldn't be there. Also look at your .htaccess files for tampering.

Check all your file and directory permissions. The Admin Tools extension can help fix permissions.

Comment: Thanks checked it but no hacking

Answer (score 0):

I have a client that had the same problem. They have a local community news site (town with a pop. 3500). They have been around for 8+ years. They were getting 3K to 4K visits daily. Most of these were bots/crawlers/spiders. This ended up eating their bandwidth. Host made them move to a dedicated server at $20 per month instead of $6. Tried a few plugins to block but they were never effective. I ended up creating a plugin for their Joomla site that allows them to block bad IP's and bots. They now get about 500 to 700 visitors daily and do not have problems with excessive CPU usage or bandwidth. Here is a link to the plugin:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/bad-bot-and-ip-blocker